# Multiselect optgroup

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I am trying to put a checkbox infront of my parent1(optgroup) and i need to make all child options as selected if i check the parent optgroup i am also attaching my code below here.so how it is possible to insert an checkbox infront of the optgroup.

```
<select id="offc" name="offc[]" multiple>
        <option value="">Select Office</option>
          <?php
           $country = array();
           foreach($office as $values)
            {
             if(!in_array($values['cntry_id'],$country))
              {
               ?>
                <optgroup label="<?php echo $values['country']?>">
               <?php
              }
              ?>
              <option value="<?php echo $values['office_id']; ?>"><?php  echo $values['listing_name']; ?></option>
             <?php 
              array_push($country,$values['cntry_id']);
             } ?>
  </select>
```

[image]

Comment: Adding the code > adding a picture, if you want some help :)

Comment: are you using bootstrap? share some code

Comment: please share some code, what you tried

Answer (score 0):

`<option>` elements can't contain HTML, so you won't be able to achieve what you want using this method. You could get a similar result by using a [Bootstrap dropdown](http://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/components/dropdowns/#forms) or similar (this is just one example, there are many options other than Bootstrap).

Answer (score 0):

When I googled "dosamigos\multiselect optgroup" I was lead here, so I'm going to answer for anyone who also ends up at this thread for Yii2 Multiselect.

It's actually quite straightforward. The data attribute that takes your array can also take a Multidimensional array where the keys are the title of the optgroup. See the following example I've left in some of the other configuration I tend to apply.

instead of:

```
$arrayOfOptions = [
    '1' => "Option 1",
    '2' => "Option 2",
    'n/a' => 'Not applicable'
];
```

You can use:

```
$arrayOfOptions = [
    'Optgroup 1' => [
        '1' => "Option 1",
        '2' => "Option 2",
    ],
    'Optgroup 2' => [
        'n/a' => 'Not applicable',
    ],
];
```

See the following for the full application of the widget.

```
$arrayOfOptions = ['1' => "Option 1", '2' => "Option 2", 'n/a' => 'Not applicable'];

MultiSelect::classname(),[
    "options" => ['multiple'=>"multiple", 'id' => 'id-attribute', 'value' => array_values($arrayOfAllOptions),'class' => 'scrollable', ], 
    'data' => ['Otp-Group-Name-1' => $arrayOfOptions, 'Otp-Group-Name-2' => ['value' => 'Text of Option']], // data as array
    'name' => 'model_attribute', // name for the form
    "clientOptions" => [
        "includeSelectAllOption" => true,
        "selectedClass" =>  'multiselect-color',
        'numberDisplayed' => 1,
        "buttonWidth" => "100%",
        "buttonClass" => "btn-multiselect-custom",
        "enableCaseInsensitiveFiltering" => true,
        "maxWidth" => "100%",
        "maxHeight" => '500',
        "selectAllText" => Yii::t('app', 'Select all'),
        "nonSelectedText" => Yii::t('app', 'Select option'),
        "filterPlaceholder" => Yii::t('app', 'Search'),
        "nSelectedText" => Yii::t('app', 'selected'),
        "allSelectedText" => Yii::t('app', 'All Selected'),
    ],
];
```